# single table vs multiple table for millions of records

Tags: sql-server-2008, sql-server-2008-r2, database-partitioning

Here's the scenario, the old database has this kind of design

```
dbo.Table1998
dbo.Table1999
dbo.Table2000
dbo.table2001
...
dbo.table2011
```

and i merged all the data from 1998 to 2011 in this table dbo.TableAllYears

now they're both indexed by "application number" and has the same numbers of columns (56 columns actually..)

now when i tried

```
select * from Table1998
```

and

```
select * from TableAllYears where Year=1998
```

the first query has 139669 rows @ 13 seconds
while the second query has same number of rows but @ 30 seconds

so for you guys, i'm i just missing something or is multiple tables better than single table?

Comment: if you could tell us which database server you're using? and version could get you good answer. To start with you could look at partitioning your table by year or month and probably add non-clustered index on the kind of queries you want to run. For SQL Server [Start Here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms345146(SQL.90).aspx)

Comment: @ Sanjeevakumar - sorry for the late reply, i didn't noticed your comment...

Comment: did you look at partitioning and indexing?

Comment: @Sanjeevakumar - I've already created indexes... but i'm bout to do partioning today... hehehe... I'll get back to this after I'm done with it and see how's the performance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should partition the table by year, this is almost equivalent to having different tables for each year. This way when you query by year it will query against a single partition and the performance will be better.

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking for data from 1998, then having only 1998 data in one table is the way to go. This is because the database doesn't have to "search" for the records, but knows that all of the records in this table are from 1998. Try adding the "WHERE Year=1998" clause to the Table1998 table and you should get a slightly better comparison.

Personally, I would keep the data in multiple tables, especially if it is a particularly large data set and you don't have to do queries on the old data frequently. Even if you do, you might want to look at creating a view with all of the table data and running the reports on that instead of having to query several tables.

Comment: Wow! that was fast... I was expecting to get my answers tom.

Comment: WOW! you're right! when i added a condition, the TableAllYears extracts faster...

Comment: oh wait, you preferred multiple tables... hmmm... ok 1 for the multiple and 0 for the single...

Comment: Yeah, without a "WHERE" clause, the database doesn't need to "filter" any records and can just return them as fast as it is able. While with a "WHERE" clause it has to figure out where the records to be returned are and then set about returning them.

Comment: I've maintained systems where the tables were split up by year like this.  It makes it incredibly painful when running queries and reports across multiple years.  You also have to keep the schemas synchronized across all the tables.  Lastly, it makes it harder to be able to implement new years without making code changes to conditionally determine what table or tables to query.

Comment: @squawknull - Actually, that was also pointed out to me by one of my colleagues. i have tested it and when it comes to my tests, (the queries on my questions.) the first one was always faster,... but as you mentioned, what if the user queries only the document number without the year...

Comment: None of your queries have a "document number" above.  But, you need an index on Year in TableAllYears or of course the performance is going to be terrible.  I have tables that have hundreds of millions of rows in the systems I maintain, and very few of my queries take more than 1 second.  140k rows is nothing, in fact, 1 million rows is nothing, in today's databases.  There has to be some other tuning that you need to do, such as index work or you have incredibly poor disk IO performance.

Comment: @squawknull - I'm testing it on my local machine, maybe once i implemented this in the server, I'll get better result. but the baseline must be in the lower specs. but the multiple table has faster result..., maybe i'll try partitioning...

Comment: You really shouldn't have to partition for that # of rows.  What database server are you using?  Mysql?  SQL Server?

Comment: Did you create an index on the Year column in TableAllYears?

Answer (score 0):

Try dropping an index on each of the columns that you're searching on (where clause). That should speed up querying dramatically.

So in this case, add a new index for the field Year.

Comment: Can you give an example that it's faster for?

Comment: select * from Table1998 = 7 secs  @ 139669 rows

and

select * from TableAllYears where Year=1998 = 13 secs @ 139669 rows

Answer (score 0):

I believe that you should use a single table.  Inevitably, you'll need to query data across multiple years, and separating it into multiple tables is a problem.  It's quite possible to optimize your query and your table structure such that you can have many millions of rows in a table and still have excellent performance.  Be sure your year column is indexed, and included in your queries.  If you really hit data size limitations, you can use partitioning functionality in MySQL 5 that allows it to store the table data in multiple files, as if it were multiple tables, while making it appear to be one table.

Regardless of that, 140k rows is nothing, and it's likely premature optimization to split it into multiple tables, and even a major performance detriment if you need to query data across multiple years.